# How to make an invisible border around a JLabel? (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border, jlabel

I have been searching how to make a border around a JLabel.  But I don't want it to have no color.  Thanks in advance.

```
public TitlePanel()
{
    title = new JLabel("This is some text!", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(title);

    //This will make a black border around the "title" label
    title.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0,0,0)));
}
```

Comment: What is a border if it is invisible?

Comment: In that case probably one with zero thickness.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu Padding, empty space, dangerous ;)

Answer (score 7):

Simply use an [`EmptyBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html)

`title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));`

Check out [How to use borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more examples

**Updated**

As suggested by Eng.Fouad, you really should be using the `BorderFactory` to generate borders.

`title.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));`

Generally speaking, this can reduce the number of objects created by the application

Comment: +1 I always use the static-factory method: `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)` ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad You're absolutely right, we should be using the factory methods as it reduces the over header and re-uses the borders. I'm just lazy that way (bad me) ;)

Comment: `Border` cannot be re-used. Actually, both are the same. Check the source code :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Really, I thought that was the point of the `BorderFactory` (mind you, it's been nearly 10 years since I last used it)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html) *Wherever possible, this factory will hand out references to shared Border instances*

Comment: I might be wrong about the re-usability of the `Border` object (I must be confused with the re-usability of swing components or layout manager objects), but most of the static-factory methods in `BorderFactory` use `return new XXXBorder();`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad It did say "where possible" :P